# Delphi Firedac master details multiple

Tags: delphi, firedac

i have 2 table in relation master-details displayed in 2 tdbgrid. Now 
 I would like to display each field on the rows of the table details in a Tedit controll, but now i view only the first row of detail in my first group of tedit.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBWid.gif)

Comment: Yes the project is VCL. I should then write a query for each row?

Comment: I should then write a query for each row? yes is VCL

Comment: "I should then write a query for each row?"  if you use a TDBCtrlGrid as in my answer there is no need.

Answer (score 2):

*If* this is a VCL project (and not a FireMonkey one), you can do this very simply.

- Place a TDBCtrlGrid on your form and set its `DataSource` for the detail dataset.
- In the IDE, the DBCtrlGrid will display a vertical series of panels, one colored solid gray and the others striped.  Place db-aware controls like TDBEdits on the solid gray panel, set their DataField properties, then compile and run.  The DBCtrlGrid has an `Orientation` property which you can set to vertical or horizontal, according to your preference.

You should see that at run-time, the DBCtrlGrid populates with as many instances of the panel and the db-aware components it contains as there are detail records, up to the number specified by the DBCtrlGrid's `RowCount` property.  If you want to ensure that there are enough copies of the panel, you could try setting the `RowCount` value to the `RecordCount' of the detail dataset in the`AfterScroll` event of the master dataset.

On the other hand, if it is a FireMonkey (FMX) project so you need to use LiveBindings (which have no TDBCtrlGrids), it *may* be possible to do this in a similar manner as you would set up controls to display the fields of the Master dataset, but I've never tried.

The following minimal VCL project code extract shows the use of a DBCtrlGrid;

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, DBCtrls, Grids, DBGrids, DB, DBClient,
  dbcgrids, Mask;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    cdsMaster: TClientDataSet;
    cdsDetail: TClientDataSet;
    dsMaster: TDataSource;
    dsDetail: TDataSource;
    gMaster: TDBGrid;
    dbnavMaster: TDBNavigator;
    gDetail: TDBGrid;
    dbnavDetail: TDBNavigator;
    DBCtrlGrid1: TDBCtrlGrid;
    DBEdit1: TDBEdit;  // placed in DBCtrlGrid1
    DBEdit2: TDBEdit;  // placed in DBCtrlGrid1
    procedure cdsMasterAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,
  j : Integer;
  Field : TIntegerField;
begin
  DBEdit1.DataField := 'MasterID';
  DBEdit2.DataField := 'DetailID';

  Field := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'MasterID';
  Field.DataSet := cdsMaster;
  cdsMaster.CreateDataSet;

  Field := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'DetailID';
  Field.DataSet := cdsDetail;
  Field := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'MasterID';
  Field.DataSet := cdsDetail;

  cdsDetail.MasterSource := dsMaster;
  cdsDetail.MasterFields := 'MasterID';
  cdsDetail.IndexFieldNames := 'MasterID;DetailID';
  cdsDetail.CreateDataSet;

  for i := 1 to 10 do begin
    cdsMaster.InsertRecord([i]);
    for j := 1 to i do
      cdsDetail.InsertRecord([j, i]);
  end;
  cdsMaster.First;
end;

procedure TForm1.cdsMasterAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  cdsDetail.DisableControls;
  try
    DBCtrlGrid1.RowCount := cdsDetail.RecordCount;
  finally
    cdsDetail.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: my connection to database is with Firedac sorry

Comment: FireDAC shouldn't make any difference, in VCL projects it supports all Delphi's db-aware components including the TDBCtrlGrid.

Comment: but I do not see them simultaneously, where am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, I can't see your project.  But there is nothing special you should need to do.  It works fine for me - for a master that has 3 details, I see 3 DBCtrlGrid panels with their DBEdits.  SO doesn't approve of screenshots, otherwise I would post one.  See e.g. http://www.imageen.com/ieforum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=2542

Comment: Sorry, its a while since I used the dBCtrlGrid and I had forgotten about its `RowCount` property - see the update to my answer.

Comment: @NuCarvignulu:  In case you are still having trouble getting the DBCtrlGrid to work, I've added a small example project to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just place a TDBEdit on the form, and then set its Datafield property and a Datasource property of a details table.

Comment: If you look at the OP's screenshot, it looks like his master table is a table of patients and the details one is a table of their prescriptions, and he seem to have TBEdits already connected to the details table.

Comment: but the lines are run only on the first group of Tedit.
I would like to see all the rows in all contemporaneamte Tedit.
It does not work even with tdctrlgrid.
There 's something that escapes me

Comment: But what you are trying to do is very much not practical, because for every new record then you would need to add more TDBEdits, and keep one thing in mind...if you are using unidirectional datasets, you can't buffer multiple records.

Comment: @NuCarvignulu:  Your youtube link does not work for me, it gives me a message "No videos found."